# How to use MPI_Bcast and MPI_Gather in a function

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I am new to MPI and trying to learn how to use MPI_Bcast and MPI_Gather inside a function. If I write the code without using a function in following way, it works fine and give the correct result:
 **Printing Result at the end:

localdata[0]:19, localdata[1]:19, localdata[2]:20, localdata[3]:20, localdata[4]:21, localdata[5]:21, localdata[6]:22, localdata[7]:22,**
To compile and Run with 4 processors, used the following commands:
`:$ mpicc test.c -o test`
`:$ mpirun -np 4 test`

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);


    int i, total;
    int arr[20];
    int localdata[8];
    if (world_rank == 0) 
    {
        for(i=0;i<20;i++)
            arr[i]=i;       

        MPI_Bcast( &arr, 20, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD );

        printf("\n\n* At Process %d received\n", world_rank);   
        for(i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            printf("ARR[%d]:%d, ",i, arr[i]);
            total=arr[i]+world_rank;
        }
        printf("\n");
        localdata[0]=total;
        localdata[1]=total;

        MPI_Gather(localdata, 2, MPI_INT, localdata, 2, MPI_INT,0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        printf("\n\nPrinting Result at the end:\n");
        for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
            printf("localdata[%d]:%d, ",i, localdata[i]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    } 
    else
    {   
        MPI_Bcast( &arr, 20, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD );

        printf("\n\n* At Process %d received\n", world_rank);   
        for(i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            printf("ARR[%d]:%d, ",i, arr[i]);
            total=arr[i]+world_rank;
        }
        printf("\n");
        localdata[0]=total;
        localdata[1]=total;

        MPI_Gather(localdata, 2, MPI_INT, localdata, 2, MPI_INT,0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }


    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

When I put these codes in a function called `function_cal`, it gives me the following error:
`*** Process received signal ***`
`Signal: Segmentation fault (11)`
`Signal code: Address not mapped (1)`
`Failing at address: 0x7fffdeb18040`
Following is the code after putting MPI_Bcast and MPI_Gather in a function. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void function_cal(int arr[20], int localdata[8], int world_rank)
{
    int i, total;

    MPI_Bcast( &arr, 20, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD );

    printf("\n\n* At Process %d received\n", world_rank);   
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        printf("ARR[%d]:%d, ",i, arr[i]);
        total=arr[i]+world_rank;
    }
    printf("\n");
    localdata[0]=total;
    localdata[1]=total;

    MPI_Gather(localdata, 2, MPI_INT, localdata, 2, MPI_INT,0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);     
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);


    int i;
    int arr[20];
    int localdata[8];
    if (world_rank == 0) 
    {
        for(i=0;i<20;i++)
            arr[i]=i;       

        function_cal(arr, localdata, world_rank);

        printf("\n\nPrinting Result at the end:\n");
        for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
            printf("localdata[%d]:%d, ",i, localdata[i]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    } 
    else
    {   
        function_cal(arr, localdata, world_rank);
    }


    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why, but changing MPI_Bcast(&arr...); to MPI_Bcast(arr...); inside the function fixes your problem. Normally, you could interchange arr and &arr since they both points to the first element of the array. This seems not be the case when the array is a function parameter.

Comment: @jahed, `arr` and `&arr` are **not** interchangeable. `arr` and `&arr[0]` are. `&arr` is a pointer to an array and has different semantics than the pointer to the first element that the array name decays to. Besides, when `arr` is a formal parameter, `&arr` is the address on the stack where the pointer to the actual argument is stored.

Comment: Another issue is that you use `localdata` on both the sending and receiving side of the `MPI_Gather()` which is explicitly forbidden by the MPI standard. If you want to do that, then use `MPI_IN_PLACE` as send buffer.

Comment: Thank you for all of your comments and guidance. They were all helpful.